# How to deploy a Daml smart contract to Hyperledger Fabric or Sawtooth?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, smartcontracts, hyperledger-sawtooth, daml

I have a smart contract in DAML and i want to deploy this smart contract to Hyperledger Fabric or Sawtooth. I can't find any tutorial about this purpose. Also, i don't find any example on the Daml documentation which tool is used to deploy the smart contract to other platform.

Comment: Apart from what already specified in one of the answers, I suggest you have a look at https://docs.daml.com/deploy/index.html, which also includes pointers to available integrations, including Fabric and Sawtooth.

Comment: Could you enlighten me about the access token file? How to create an access token file? Any example?

Answer (score 3):

The open source DAML on Sawtooth and DAML on Fabric integrations built by partners BTP and HACERA can be found here in github, and instructions on how to run the respective network locally for the purposes of development and evaluation are included in the readmes

Hyperledger Sawtooth
https://github.com/blockchaintp/daml-on-sawtooth

Hyperledger Fabric
https://github.com/hacera/daml-on-fabric

For a fully supported production usage of DAML on Sawtooth, please see the BTP Sextant offering via AWS Marketplace
https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B07Z8HPN96

Once you have spun up the network, you can allocate parties and upload your DAR files using the DAML assistant tool that is part of the DAML SDK, which I assume you have already installed if you have already built smart contracts in DAML
https://docs.daml.com/getting-started/installation.html

The daml ledger upload-dar and daml ledger allocate-parties commands will be the ones you want to use to initialize the ledger with the specific of your application, and ensure you specific the correct --host and --port for the running ledger.

Comment: Thank you Brian! I tried the quickstart tutorial on fabric and it works. However, i have a smart contract in daml and i have some scripts in which i use dazl package (python) to interact with the ledger but the dazl package does not work on fabric. Do you know if is possible to use python or is acceptable only the official bindings( java,node, scala) to interact with the other ledgers?